# If I made a incandescent light bulb filament smaller what would happen?

Tags: power-engineering

If I took the filament in the bulb and made it smaller, and also increase the thickness of it, what would happen?

Comment: Could you include more details? What exactly are you interested in? Are you wondering about the brightness of the bulb, or the power consumption, or the filament temperature? A lot of things could 'happen', what specifically do you want to know?

Comment: @BarbalatsDilemma sorry filament temperature is important right now so that's what this deal with

Answer (score 1):

All other things being equal,  the resistance of a wire is inversely proportional to its cross-section and proportional to its length.   You could think of increasing the cross-section as analogous to resistors in parallel, and increasing the length as analogous to resistors in series.

So, pick a given filament, find its resistance, then apply the factors I listed to find the new resistance.   Assuming a "stiff" voltage source, you have a constant voltage, so the power dissipated is $ \frac{V^2}{R} $